# Angular reactive form - custom validator

Tags: angular

I have a requirement that certain input fields need to be masked. Example, desired amount should be displayed as $44,444. I can achieve the input masking by using text-mask (https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask). The problem I am encountering is that the masking breaks my reactive form validators.

component:

```
import {WithinLoanRangeDirective} from './within-loan-range.directive'

this.applicationForm = this.fb.group({
  desiredAmount: ['', [Validators.required, WithinLoanRangeDirective] ]
})
```

template:

```
<input
 [textMask]="{mask: numberMask}"
 mdInput
 formControlName="desiredLoanAmount   
 type="tel"            
 > <!--type tel to pop numpad-->

<div> {{ applicationForm.controls['desiredLoanAmount'].hasError('withinLoanAmountRange')}}</div>
```

The validators are now checking min and max against the masked input ($44,444) instead of  (44444). Is there a way to format the value before setting it in model?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom validator (Directive) and strip out all non-numeric characters and set a min max as arguments (or hard code them in the directive..), then return the validity.

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngModel][withinLoanAmountRange], [formControl][withinLoanAmountRange]',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useClass: WithinLoanRangeDirective,
            multi: true,
        }
    ]
})
export class WithinLoanRangeDirective implements Validator {
    constructor() { 
    }
    validate(c: FormControl) {
        let loanValue = c.value.replace(/\D/g,''); 

        return (loanValue >= 1000 && loanValue <= 20000) ? null : {
            withinLoanAmountRange: { message: 'Loan Needs to be between 1 and $5k' }
        };
    }
}




<input
 [textMask]="{mask: numberMask}"
 withinLoanAmountRange
 mdInput
 formControlName="desiredLoanAmount              
 >
```

Comment: How do I get that withinLoanAmountRange.message back in the template? Think I am missing something to get this wired up. I put a console.log(loanValue) after "let loanValue" and nothing gets printed to console when typing.

Comment: `applicationForm .controls['desiredLoanAmount            '].hasError('withinLoanAmountRange'))` in the template

Comment: Alternatively, you can import the directive into the component and add it into the validators array, instead of in the template.

Comment: `import { WithinLoanRangeDirective} from '../....directive';`

`desiredAmount: ['', [Validators.required, WithinLoanRangeDirective] ]`

Comment: Updated original question with my implementation. My directive is exactly as you posted above. The error returned to template is always false.

Comment: mess around with the code a bit..I free handed this. your fields names dont match up. Might want to check the types in the comparison.  maybe parseInt on the loanAmount in the directive or add a + to the beginning to cast it.